# How to add attributes to Grails 3 CSS files via asset-pipeline

Tags: css, grails, asset-pipeline, grails-3.0

I am including css files using asset-pipeline via application.css and my bootstrap css files require me to add attributes `media="screen, projection"`

Currently I am adding:

```
*= require /webjars/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme
*= require /webjars/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap
*= require /webjars/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.5/bootstrap-tagsinput
```

to my application.css which is producing:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.css?compile=false">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css?compile=false">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/bootstrap-multi-level-dropdown.css?compile=false">
```

How do I for example generate the following html?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.css?compile=false" media="screen, projection">
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass in the media attribute as extra parameters to the  tag.

> Any attributes other than those described below will be forwarded to the  element generated by this tag.

[Source](http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/ref/Tags/stylesheet.html)

E.G.,

`<asset:stylesheet src="application.css" media="screen, projection"/>`